# Puxar valor de tabela vertical para horizontal

Tags: microsoft-excel

a Tabela 2 é a Tabela transposta da Tabela 1.

Pesquisei bastante e não encontrei solução, gostaria de que quando eu puxasse o valor pra baixo ali no “25,16” da Tabela 2 ele mostrasse o valor seguinte ao “25,16” da Tabela 1, que seria nulo, porém ele puxa o valor da linha da Tabela 1 na Tabela 2, e aparece o 1,94%. Tem como fazer isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Teria como dar mais detalhes como qual a linguagem está fazendo a transposição, o código usado e uma amostra de dados para teste. Veja [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Para a solução deste problema utilize a fórmula de Array {=Transpor(matriz)}.

Selecione o local aonde deseja que as novas informações sejam transpostas invertendo as quantidade de números e colunas, ou seja A1:D14(4 Colunas; 14 Linhas) será transposta em F1:S4 (14 Colunas; 4 Linhas).

[image: Definição do local a ser transposto]
Após selecionar, insira a fórmula =Transpor(matriz), substituindo "matriz" pela tabela que deseja transpor. No caso a formula final será =TRANSPOR(A1:D14), porém não aperte "enter" ainda.

[image: Inserção da Fórmula]

Ao invés de apertar "enter", aperte junto as teclas "ctrl+shift+enter", desta forma será criado um Array com as informações transpostas.

A formula final ficará da seguinte forma: {=TRANSPOR(A1:D14)}

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).